# bxSlider implementation: my code is not working.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

```
<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="ASHLEYSIMONE/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="ASHLEYSIMONE/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
    });
</script>
```

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="/images/pic1.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/pic2.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/pic3.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/pic4.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

I've checked others users answers regarding this issue but I still can't figure it out. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Please help. This part is preventing me from finishing my site.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying to http:// for your first library.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: When I put the code in JSFIDDLE. It works. When I use the code in Coda . It doesn't work...

Comment: @user2833791 Are you running the code locally through Coda? Do you have a development site/server where you can upload your changes and check against different browsers (on the live site).

Comment: Thanks guys...your advice helped me figured it out